# How do you disable cellular data use for all apps except for one?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any way to disable all the background applications except WhatsApp for cellular connections? I have WhatsApp plan only from my carrier, I want to only use WhatsApp when I turn on the cellular connection.
I dont see WhatsApp / Facebook or main apps in cellular section "Use cellular data for" but only default apple apps.

How to disable for cellular only?

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the "Use Cellular Data For" section looks like?

Comment: Firstly, are you saying that if you go to Settings -> Cellular, under Use Mobile Data For, Facebook and Whatsapp aren't shown there even though they are installed? Secondly, unfortunately there is no way to turn off system use of data. You can turn off every other app's data usage (providing it shows in that list of course!), but not the system services.

Comment: @Peanut i have shared the images

Comment: @TimMalone - i have shared the images , you can see that whatsapp is present in background app section but not in cellular app section, thanks for letting me know that i cant disable system services but at least these should be disabled in cellular

Comment: @ShanKhan Weird, I've never seen that before! I don't suppose you can try uninstalling and reinstalling Whatsapp?

Comment: @TimMalone i have tried this. nothing happened , even there are alot of apps not only facebook but skype , snapchat etc that are showing in background but not on cellular. i have IOS 9.3.1 is there any way i can resintall this IOS again from the apple online or any other way.

Comment: This is probably now a different question - I'd suggest posting a question asking why these apps might not be on the cellular data list. I'm afraid I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Settings menu, once you've scrolled past Twitter/Facebook/Flickr/Vimeo, you can see all of your installed apps. Tap any app, and you can uncheck Background App Refresh and Cellular Data individually.  Do that for every app except WhatsApp, and you should be set!